# Replacing an LED power supply - but originally there were 2 supplies connected parallel

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, led-driver

I have a LED lamp. It went wrong and I found out that it's power supply is the cause.

Originally two of these supplies were connected *parallel* (their output connected parallel):

- Input: AC90-265V 50/60Hz
- Output: DC56-82V 300mA +-5%
- Load: (40-50)*1W LED

[image]

Is it true (roughly - as a rule-of-thumb) that their common output is somewhere around 600mA (what is the sane reason for connecting SMPSs' outputs)?

I want to replace these PSs but I haven't found the same ones. What I found is a bit different but same in current:

- Input: AC100-240V 50/60Hz (OK)
- Output: DC60-120V 300mA (OK? If the originals were not below 60V)

[image]

Can I connect these new ones in parallel and then to the lamp?

What are the pros and cons?

This is how the lamp behaves when I attach two parallel supplies on both of its sides: https://youtu.be/lKY6Hkomf0Q

Thanks!

Comment: make sure the lamps can be connected in parallel. That is only possible if they have current control.

Comment: There is only one lamp which contains a lot of LEDs. I think they are all connected in parallel. But I did not touch the LEDs. I have only examined their power supply. The power supplies were connected in parallel. I.e.: PS1's positive output is connected to PS2's positive output AND PS1's negative output is connected to PS2's negative output. Then the common negative output is connected to the lamp's negative and the common positive output is connected to the lamp's positive.

Comment: I meant the power supplies should be able to be conncected parallel. That is only possible if they have a current loop internally (most of them have)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the drivers are constant-current-output drivers, but make sure they are so.

It's perfectly fine to connect those drivers in parallel: Each one regulates its output, and has a series diode to prevent any false current to flow through the other.

The intention of connecting the constant-current LED drivers in parallel is to reach the required output power. If the LED load is, say, 40W (e.g. 65V x 0.6A) and you have only 25W drivers with the same output current, then you can parallel them. Their output current may differ *(e.g. one has 300mA yet the other has 295mA)* but the total current (the sum of the two) will flow through the LED load. That's what you expect.

PS: Some users turn on the driver first unloaded, then plug the LED load in. Don't do that. Because, if the driver operates unloaded then its output voltage can reach to the maximum value allowed (e.g. 120VDC for yours). This high voltage may harm your LED load when you plug it in. So, connect the LED load to the driver then turn the driver on.

Comment: "Don't do that." - of course 120V is way more than 85 which was the original. I would never do that :) Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check my update? Why could this happen with the lamp?

Comment: @Daniel did you connect two of Chanzon drivers? Are they connected parallel?

Comment: @Daniel what I can see from the video is that the drivers activate their overload protection.

Comment: "did you connect two of Chanzon drivers?" - yes, connected them parallel. However after that I tried with a single Chanzon and it was all the same (flashing).

Comment: "overload protection": can make sense, however the original supply was 56-85V 300mA, and Chanzon is 60-120V 300mA, how can it be less powerful than the original?

Comment: @Daniel maybe the Chanzon driver is not what it advertises.